# Unsupported subtype for CID font /CIDFontType0C

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-4.6.1

I'm using [PdfPig](https://github.com/UglyToad/PdfPig) to read text from a pdf:

```
using (var document = PdfDocument.Open(filePath))
{
    var page = document.GetPage(0);
}
```

I'm getting an exception on `document.GetPage(0);`:

```
System.NotSupportedException

Unsupported subtype for CID font /CIDFontType0C. Font: UglyToad.PdfPig.Fonts.CompactFontFormat.CompactFontFormatFontProgram
```

I assume the pdf has an unrecognized font.
How can I get around this?
Is there something I can do with the code to avoid this exception?
Or can I change the font programmatically?

I'm using PdfPig v0.0.5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update to the latest version **0.1.4**

I'm just complete it with PDF files with CIDFont, and it works.